# Google Sheets query date > today()

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to filter out dates greater than today. I looked up the syntax but the date-part does not work; I'm still getting dates > today in the results.
Could someone help me out with this?! Thank you! Here' the query:

```
=iferror(sort(if(isblank(Sheet1!B1),
query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TWDHeriSlgHYKYmfwNxVm_4apbuavrX94itSpEykBI4/edit#gid=1635810036","responses!b2:l"),"select *"),query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TWDHeriSlgHYKYmfwNxVm_4apbuavrX94itSpEykBI4/edit#gid=1635810036","responses!b2:l"),
"select * WHERE Col1 = '"&Sheet1!$B$1&"'AND Col2 > date'"&TEXT(today(),"dd-mm-yyyy")&"'")),2,true),"no results")
```

Answer (score 8):

You might want to try replacing part of your formula with:

```
date '"&text(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"'
```

possibly reversing the angled bracket, and reading about [**minimal** complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

[Ref](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/74119/60716)

Answer (score 4):

The following formula should work, issue is in the space between `>` and `date` and how you placed the `"` and `'`

```
=iferror(sort(if(isblank(Sheet1!B1),
query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TWDHeriSlgHYKYmfwNxVm_4apbuavrX94itSpEykBI4/edit#gid=1635810036","responses!b2:l"),"select *"),query(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TWDHeriSlgHYKYmfwNxVm_4apbuavrX94itSpEykBI4/edit#gid=1635810036","responses!b2:l"),
"select * WHERE Col1 = '"&Sheet1!$B$1&"' AND Col2 > date '"&TEXT(today(),"dd-mm-yyyy")&"'")),2,true),"no results")
```

Answer (score 2):

```
where Col5 > date' "&TEXT(today(),"yyyy-mm-dd")&" '
```

That is what I used.